# How do I connect an array of buttons w/i singleton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder

My appDelegate, in the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I load my view controller then create a singleton:

```
UIViewController *MainWinVC = [[p3VC alloc] init];
[[self window] setRootViewController:MainWinVC];
ansButSingleton *ansButs = [[ansButSingleton alloc] init];
```

ansButSingleton.h looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ansButSingleton : NSObject {

    // View objects:

    UIButton *Ans1;
    UIButton *Ans2;
    UIButton *Ans3;
    UIButton *Ans4;
    UIButton *Ans5;
    UIButton *Ans6;
    UIButton *Ans7;
    UIButton *Ans8;

    // Other objects:

    NSArray *ansButs;

}

@property (strong) UIButton *Ans1, *Ans2, *Ans3, *Ans4, *Ans5, *Ans6, *Ans7, *Ans8;
@property (strong) NSArray *ansButs;

+ (ansButSingleton *) ansButsName;  // Declare class method
@end
```

and ansButSingleton.m like this:

```
#import "ansButSingleton.h"

@implementation ansButSingleton

static ansButSingleton *ansButsName;

@synthesize Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, Ans5, Ans6, Ans7, Ans8;
@synthesize ansButs;

//////////////////// instantiate ////////////////////

+ (ansButSingleton *) ansButsName { // class method

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!ansButsName)
            ansButsName = [[ansButSingleton alloc] init];        
        return ansButsName;
    }
}

//////////////////// initialize ////////////////////

- (id)init { // class instance method

    NSLog(@"Initializing answer buttons");

    if (ansButsName) {
        return ansButsName;
    }

    self = [super init];

    if(self) {

        // First initialze the individual buttons

        self.Ans1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [Ans1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.Ans2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [Ans2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.Ans3 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [Ans3 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.Ans4 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [Ans4 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.Ans5 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [Ans5 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.Ans6 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [Ans6 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.Ans7 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [Ans7 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.Ans8 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [Ans8 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // Make an array containing the objects: this is the objective-C way!

        self.ansButs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, Ans5, Ans6, Ans7, Ans8, nil];
    }

    NSLog(@"Done initializing answer buttons");

    return self;
}
@end
```

This builds and runs fine (it doesn't do much yet).  The buttons are visible due to the successful loading of the nib.  However, they are not active since I haven't connected them to the code (no IBActions).

Question:  How do I connect buttons created this way to the buttons in the nib?  If these were simple buttons (not an array of buttons) I would create a method and use IBAction as part of that method declaration.  But this case seems a bit different.  Or maybe not.  If these were labels (which I also need to do later), my reading leads me to believe IBOutletCollection might work, but there is no IBActionCollection that I can see.  Expert guidance needed!  Thanks.

EDIT ... working with Rob to implement his ideas.  My viewLoad method was copied and pasted from yours, but maybe there was something in it I needed to change?

```
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

 - (void)loadView {
 NSDictionary *externals = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[AnswerButtons answerButtons]
 forKey:@"answerButtons"];
 NSDictionary *nibOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:externals
 forKey:UINibExternalObjects];
 [self.nibBundle loadNibNamed:self.nibName owner:self options:nibOptions];
 [[AnswerButtons answerButtons] buttonsDidLoad];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this.  I'd do it by hooking up the singleton's connections in the nib.  Here's how.

First, let's fix up the singleton class to match iOS programming conventions and provide the support for wiring up the button connections in the nib:

#### AnswerButtons.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AnswerButtons : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1, *button2, *button3, *button4, *button5, *button6, *button7, *button8;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *buttons;

+ (AnswerButtons *)answerButtons;

- (void)buttonsDidLoad;

@end
```

#### AnswerButtons.m

```
#import "AnswerButtons.h"

@implementation AnswerButtons

@synthesize button1 = _button1;
@synthesize button2 = _button2;
@synthesize button3 = _button3;
@synthesize button4 = _button4;
@synthesize button5 = _button5;
@synthesize button6 = _button6;
@synthesize button7 = _button7;
@synthesize button8 = _button8;

@synthesize buttons = _buttons;

+ (AnswerButtons *)answerButtons {
    static AnswerButtons *singleton;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        singleton = [[AnswerButtons alloc] init];
    });
    return singleton;
}

- (void)buttonsDidLoad {
    _buttons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_button1, _button2, _button3, _button4, _button5, _button6, _button7, _button8, nil];
}

@end
```

**Note that we create** the singleton in the class method the first time the singleton is requested.  Don't do it in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Next, let's hook up the buttons in the nib:

1. Open the nib for the `p3VC` class.  (You should consider changing this name to start with a capital letter and spell out `ViewController` or just `Controller`.)
2. Drag an “External Object” from the Object Library into the nib.
3. In the Identity Inspector, set the External Object's custom class to `AnswerButtons`.
4. In the Attributes Inspector, set its External Object Identifier to `answerButtons`.
5. Control-drag from the Answer Buttons object to each of the eight buttons, connecting the button to the appropriate outlet.

Finally, we need to provide the `AnswerButtons` singleton to the nib loader when we load the nib.  Edit `p3VC.m` and give it a `loadView` method:

#### p3VC.m

```
- (void)loadView {
    NSDictionary *externals = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[AnswerButtons answerButtons]
        forKey:@"answerButtons"];
    NSDictionary *nibOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:externals
        forKey:UINibExternalObjects];
    [self.nibBundle loadNibNamed:self.nibName owner:self options:nibOptions];
    [[AnswerButtons answerButtons] buttonsDidLoad];
}
```

With this approach, you can also create `IBAction` methods in the `AnswerButtons` class and use the nib to connect the buttons to those actions.

Comment: [delay due to "life"] Thanks Rob, this is a huge help!  Can you tell I'm coming from a different language?  I've been cobbling together ideas -- for instance, my singleton came from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like  (I do see that folks have lots of ways of doing the same thing).  Will buttonsDidLoad init the buttons with no titles?  Or do I need to add [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; that Seany242 suggested?  It'sll take me a few days to study all this, but again, a huge thanks.

Comment: I think I have everything as you specified (instructions nice & clear), but it throws an exception: 2012-02-05 20:46:39.721 P3[7277:f803] Missing proxy for identifier answerButtons
2012-02-05 20:46:39.730 P3[7277:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIProxyObject 0x6a4a4d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key button1.' Did I miss soemthing?  Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and paste in your `loadView` method.

Comment: loadView added to orginal question.  Thank you.

Comment: Those messages appear when you don't put an object in the external objects dictionary with a key that matches the External Object Identifier in the nib.  Make sure that you don't have any extra whitespace in that Identifier field in the nib.

Comment: I have uploaded my test project in case you want to compare. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26919672/bignib.zip

Comment: Thanks much for the sample project.  I've been studying it carefully.  My poor little nib has an ugly history, a victim of several learning cycles. I deleted it and created a new leaner nib.  I hooked it up.  I still have the same error message.  Looking at your project, you have a connection between Object View and the "file's owner" listed under referencing outlets in the connection inspector.  I don't have one of these, and though I've tried many variations, I can't find a way to make that connection.  Hoping for one more nugget of your wisdom!

Comment: Click on File's Owner.  Then from the menu bar choose View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector.  In the Identity Inspector (right-hand side of the Xcode window), go to the Custom Class text field.  Enter the name of your view controller class (the class that contains the `loadView` method).  In my test project, the view controller class name is just `ViewController`.  I guess in your project the class name is `p3VC`.  You should then be able to control-drag from File's Owner to the top-level view and connect the view to the `view` outlet of File's Owner.

Comment: Thanks, I made this connection.  Then I had the wrong nib showing up even though it was deleted. I compared each of my files to the ones you shared, and found that even though the name of nib file was correct in the plist, you didn't have such an entry.  I deleted mine, and voila, I was in business.  I'm back to development instead of troubleshooting, and I'm most grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Since `UIButton` inherits from `UIControl` you can use the method:

```
[yourButton1 addTarget:yourObject action:@selector(yourMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hook that in the loop where the buttons are created and you are good to go. If you are adding the buttons from interface builder then you need to hook an `IBOutlet` for each. Example: In your view controller `init`:

```
 self.Ans1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
 [Ans1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//set the action
    [Ans1 addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Another way would be to create the `IBAction` method for each button and hook that method to the method in the singleton, which in my opinion is much more clear.

Example: in your view controller:

```
-(IBAction) button1Press:(id)sender{

[yourSingleton button1Press];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- it'll take me a while to play with this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second method?  Do you mean create a IBAction method for each button in the normal way?  Where should I put that code if that's what you meant?

Comment: I think I can see how to use your suggestion once my app is past initialization, but if you double check my code above this is during initialization, so no one is around to click the button.  I need to set the title of the button to an empty string.  These buttons will change their title when they are clicked (somewhat like a UILabel).  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I guess I can call the method with an argument to set the title to "" during initialization.  I'll try it like that.  Sorry for baby steps here.

Answer (score 1):

To connect the buttons to interface builder, you'd have to place "IBOutlet" before the UIButton in each one of your variable declarations.

```
IBOutlet UIButton * Ans1;
```

Then in interface builder, you can right click and drag from view controller onto the button and select the right button. Then if you wanted to have each button perform a method, you should declare an IBAction method in your .h file:

```
-(IBAction)doButtonStuff:(id)sender;
```

Then to hook up the act to each button in interface builder, go to interface builder and right click and drag from the button to view controller and select what method you want to associate it with. Typically using interface builder is quick and easy but if you want to do some extra behind the scenes stuff, you can use the code whitelion posted.
Also, just a side note, to use less code when setting up your buttons, you can do a for each loop.

```
for (UIButton * button in ansButs) {
    self.button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

This is a lot less code!!! You'd have to declare the array before this code and include all of the buttons in it.